# __dirname mangles url in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an Electron app in which I'm executing this line: `path.join(__dirname, '/assets/' + template)`.

Using a debugger, I can see that `__dirname` is:

**C:\Users\Primordial_Hamster\Documents\GitHub\desktop\app\.webpack\main**

and the result of `'/assets/' + template` is: **/assets/file.html**.

I expect the result of the above call to `path.join()` to be:

**C:/Users/Primordial_Hamster/Documents/GitHub/desktop/app/.webpack/main/assets/file.html**.

Yet for some reason, the result of running the above line is:

**C:/Users/Primordial_Hamster/Documents/GitHub/desktop/app/undefinedassets/file.html**.

I suppose I can workaround it by concatenating the two parts myself, but I'm curious why might the result be this strange mangled string? Strangely enough, the result of `__dirname + '/assets/' + template` is once again, the same string, so this is clearly an issue with `__dirname`. If I cast `__dirname` to string first, then the manual concatenation works.

Full code supplied below:

**src/main/documents.js**

```js
const { ipcMain, BrowserWindow, app } = require("electron");
const path = require('path');

let popup;

const createDocument = (template, title, data) => {
    popup = new BrowserWindow({
        show: true,
        title: title,
        parent: global.mainWindow,
        modal: true,
        icon: path.join(__dirname, '/assets/hr.ico'), // This works normally for some reason
        resizable: true,
    });
    popup.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, '/assets' + template), data);
    popup.setMenu(null);

    popup.show();
};

ipcMain.on('document', (event, template, title, data) => {
    createDocument(template, title, data);
});
```

Comment: Not working after pack?

Comment: Try changing the plus sign (+) to a comma (,) in you `path.join()` line of code. See [path.join()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v21.x/docs/api/path.html#pathjoinpaths) for more information.

Comment: @midnight-coding I did try that, but it's not the issue.